# how can i change the pagination banner of display lag

Tags: java, struts2, pagination, displaytag

I am using display tag pagination where i get banner like this

```
63 items found, displaying 1 to 10.[First/Prev] `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 [Next/Last]`
```

but i want it like this

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 [Next/Last]
```

is there any property to customize pagination banner 
the pagination page is

```
    <display:table name="groupInfoBeanList" list="groupInfoBeanList" pagesize="10" requestURI="manageGroupLink" decorator="com.cdr.Decorator.CheckBoxDecorator" class="table table-striped">
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom" />
        <display:column property="checkBox" title="Select" />
        <display:column property="groupId" title="Group Id" sortable="true" />
        <display:column property="groupDescription" title="Group Description"   />
        <display:column property="companyType" title="Company Type" sortable="true" />
        <display:column property="companyName" title="Company Name" sortable="true" />
    </display:table>
```

Comment: atleast please reply to question specially those who gave negative to this question

Comment: please post your pagination tag ?

Comment: @amrola i edit the question as you said

Comment: post you Tag class of the table tag

Comment: display:table is a Custom tag right ?

Comment: @Amrola sorry don't know what do you mean by tag class.

Comment: @Amrola is it the action class from which the list is coming to this jsp

Comment: no not the action class , from where did you get this pagination ?

Comment: @Amrola there is not any tag class. In display tag you just have to write "pagesize" attribute and pagination is done

Comment: i know , i saw the code , what i am asking from where you get this ? 
you want me to help or what  ?

Comment: @Amrola I am using struts framework and this is my jsp page and the list i pass in display tag comes from an action class.

Comment: try to use the summary="" in the display:table

Comment: i am working on it at the moment

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is change The default properties are defined in the TableTag.properties file included in the library jar.

please refer to this [link](http://www.displaytag.org/10/configuration.html) to see how to override default property settings

using the  tag like the following :

```
<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.full" value="<span class="pagelinks"> [ <a href="{3}">Next</a>/ <a href="{4}">Last </a>]</span> " />
```

and please give me some feedback

Hope that Helps .

Comment: i already tried these properties like "paging.banner.placement" is in my jsp but all others is not working.

Comment: not in your jsp , they are telling you how to do that in the link i provided

Comment: or yes you can do that in the jsp using the  <display:setProperty>
did you tried the  <display:setProperty> tag?

Comment: yes i tried <display:setProperty> but it's not working. I think you can also try see if u get it right

Comment: no it's not working still getting the same output

Answer (score 0):

Use this property 
`<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.group_size" value="7"/>`

This will allow you to display 7 pages on the pagination bar.

Comment: Works for me, thanks.